# Mockito always returns null as a result of calling an EJB

Tags: java, mockito, ejb, java-ee-8

I'm trying to call the second method of this class, and always get `null`. Note that it returns `new User()` however in the test class I always get `null`:

```
@Stateless
public class UserDAO2 {

    public Connection getConnFromPool(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    public User readByUserid(String s) {
        System.out.println("In DAO 2");
        Connection c = getConnFromPool(1);
        return new User();
    }
}
```

And the test class:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserBeanUnitTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private UserDAO2 dao2;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        dao2 = Mockito.mock(UserDAO2.class);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }


    @Test
    public void testBean() {

        Mockito.when(dao2.getConnFromPool(1)).thenReturn(null);

        User expectedUser = new User();
        expectedUser.setSk(1);
        expectedUser.setFirstName("David");
        expectedUser.setLastName("Gahan");
        expectedUser.setUserid("user1");

        User user = dao2.readByUserid("user1"); // <-- this method always returns null

        assertThat(user).isEqualTo(expectedUser); // <-- test fails as expectedUser != null

    }

}
```

Also, note that `System.out.println` is never printed. How to fix this to actually make a call to `dao.readByUserid()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to test the method of some class, and inside of it the other method of the same class is called which you want to mock, then you need to use `@Spy`:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserDAO2Test {

    @InjectMocks
    @Spy
    private UserDAO2 dao;

    @Test
    public void testBean() {

        Mockito.doReturn(null).when(dao).getConnFromPool(1);

        User expectedUser = new User();
        expectedUser.setSk(1);
        expectedUser.setFirstName("David");
        expectedUser.setLastName("Gahan");
        expectedUser.setUserid("user1");

        User user = dao.readByUserid("user1");

        assertThat(user).isEqualTo(expectedUser);
    }
}
```

Note that I slightly modified the line with mocking `getConnFromPool` because it's required when you use that technique.

See [docs](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) for spying.

Comment: I do need to mock the class, as I need to do `Mockito.when(dao.getConnFromPool(1)).thenReturn(null);`. The question I posted is a simplification.

Comment: if you test `readByUserid` method then you don't need to mock `getConnFromPool` because it's not called in it.

Comment: In the real code it is called, I just didn't put it in the question. I adjusted the question to avoid any confusions.

Comment: Sorry, but `dao.readByUserid` still returns null, maybe the `@Stateless` annotation is creating the problem?

Comment: Very strange, `MockitoJUnitRunner` should ignore this annotation. Maybe something else is missing in the example from the question because I've tested this code and the test worked correctly.

Comment: The code is identical, it's what I put in the question, still get null. Not sure what could be the problem, I'm running this on Eclipse/JUnit 4 and the method always returns null.

Comment: I made an example: https://github.com/amseager/spytest. You could try it and then compare it with your code. Maybe we're missing something.

Comment: I just replaced the code and it worked, I don't know what was wrong with mine, I will build on top of your code

Comment: The difference with your code is that I had `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` I use this in other examples and it works fine, not sure why it creates a conflict here.